# How to club record for same date in array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

This is a response I'm getting from an API I'm calling.

```
[
  {
    "id": 54,
    "profileId": 9,
    "sessionStartedOn": "2021-02-25T07:34:26.123Z",
    "sessionEndedOn": "2021-02-25T12:34:26.123Z",
    "sessionStartedFromIP": "string",
    "sessionEndedFromIP": "string",
    "sessionStartedFromAgent": "string",
    "sessionEndedFromAgent": "string",
    "isSessionEndedBySystem": true,
    "sessionEndedBySystemOn": "2021-02-25T10:34:26.123Z",
    "comment": "string",
    "sessionDuration": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 55,
    "profileId": 9,
    "sessionStartedOn": "2021-03-04T04:34:26.123Z",
    "sessionEndedOn": null,
    "sessionStartedFromIP": "string",
    "sessionEndedFromIP": "string",
    "sessionStartedFromAgent": "string",
    "sessionEndedFromAgent": "string",
    "isSessionEndedBySystem": false,
    "sessionEndedBySystemOn": null,
    "comment": "active sessition",
    "sessionDuration": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 56,
    "profileId": 9,
    "sessionStartedOn": "2021-02-25T07:34:26.123Z",
    "sessionEndedOn": "2021-02-25T13:34:26.123Z",
    "sessionStartedFromIP": "string",
    "sessionEndedFromIP": "string",
    "sessionStartedFromAgent": "string",
    "sessionEndedFromAgent": "string",
    "isSessionEndedBySystem": true,
    "sessionEndedBySystemOn": "2021-02-25T07:34:26.123Z",
    "comment": "after lunch break",
    "sessionDuration": 0
  }
]
```

I want to club record for same date so that I can calculate difference between time of records on same date (sign in time and sign out time)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array reduce function to group items.

```
let groupedResponse = response.reduce(function (response, item) {
    let key = new Date(item.sessionStartedOn).toLocaleDateString();
    response[key] = response[key] || [];
    response[key].push(item);
    return response;
}, Object.create(null));
console.log(groupedResponse)
{
 04/03/2021: [{…}]
 25/02/2021: (2) [{…}, {…}]
}
```

After grouping, you can use the array sort function to sort items.

```
for(let date in groupedResponse) {
   let dateItems = groupedResponse[date];
   let sortedDateItems = dateItems.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.sessionStartedOn).getTime() > new Date(b.sessionStartedOn).getTime()) ? 1 : -1);
   //apply calculations on sortedDateItems array
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply 
I want to calculate break time duration between two dates entered for same day and club that two record into single. 
Break will be calculated basis on 1 record sessionEndedOn - 2 record SessionStartedOn
club 2 record into one, with use of  1 record sessionStartedOn time and 2 record SessionEndedOn time

Comment: { comment: "string" id: 37 isSessionEndedBySystem: true profileId: 9 profileName: "abc " sessionDuration: 6 sessionEndedBySystemOn: "2021-02-25T10:34:26.123Z" sessionEndedFromAgent: "string" sessionEndedFromIP: "string" sessionEndedOn: "2021-02-25T13:34:26.123Z" sessionStartedFromAgent: "string" sessionStartedFromIP: "string" sessionStartedOn: "2021-02-25T05:34:26.123Z", breakTime:{{calculate time duration}}, breaks: 1 }


expected output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply Akif,your answered help me lot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMa4i.png)

I want to calculate break time duration between two dates entered for same day and club that two record into single

expected o/p

{
comment: "string"
id: 37
isSessionEndedBySystem: true
profileId: 9
profileName: "abc "
sessionDuration: 6
sessionEndedBySystemOn: "2021-02-25T10:34:26.123Z"
sessionEndedFromAgent: "string"
sessionEndedFromIP: "string"
sessionEndedOn: "2021-02-25T13:34:26.123Z"
sessionStartedFromAgent: "string"
sessionStartedFromIP: "string"
sessionStartedOn: "2021-02-25T05:34:26.123Z",
breakTime:{{calculate time duration}},
breaks: 1
}

logic

1. break will be calculated basis on
   1 record sessionEndedOn - 2 record SessionStartedOn
2. club 2 record into one
   1 record sessionStartedOn time and 2 record SessionEndedOn time

Thank you